# Use Apex to trigger process builder

Tags: trigger, process-builder

I created an object in sfdc to take snapshots of Account financial information each year.

I'm using process builder to stamp the account financial info on the custom object record.

I know that process builder doesn't allow you to trigger it when a formula field updates (I created a last_day_of_year checkbox; when marked true fire the process but didn't work). Is there any way I can use apex or another method to start this process in order to create the custom object record at the end of the year to take the snapshot?

Comment: Have you considered scheduling a Flow to run at year end?

Comment: No I have not. Any recommendations on how to build the flow?

Comment: You can get a good start at Salesforce Trailhead, as well as Salesforce-related Youtube channels and other resources on the web.

Comment: Okay Im seeing you can choose the date but it looks like I would have to come in every year and update it

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange. I've not yet created a scheduled Flow, so was not aware of that limitation. But it looks like there might be a workaround: https://forcepanda.wordpress.com/2020/03/03/how-to-schedule-flows-to-run-every-month-year/ | I did not read through it to see if it was actually relevant to what you are trying to do, so sorry if it is not actually helpful.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://douglascayers.com/2016/04/18/salesforce-process-builder-scheduler/  Otherwise you'll have to write scheduled Apex.

Comment: you can have the scheduled flow run every day and its first decision block is to see whether the current date is the last day of the year; if not, NOP; otherwise, do work

Comment: Thanks. I tried the flow option but it doesn't seem to work. I need it to create a record for each account where the date checkbox is marked as true. It only created 1 record and didn't populate any of the fields I mapped. I feel like this should be a pretty simple functionality.